# Is it possible to request a new plot type in pgfplots, and if so, how?

Tags: pgfplots

Some days ago I posted a question about creating an xycomb plot in pgfplot here: [There's xcomb and ycomb in pgfplots, but is there something like an xycomb?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/657559/theres-xcomb-and-ycomb-in-pgfplots-but-is-there-something-like-an-xycomb/657585#657585). A scan of the pgfplots' online gallery and the deafening silence in response to my post (one suggestion but not in pgfplots) leads me to believe there is no such plot type and that pgfplots can't be tricked into producing one.

If that is true, is there a way for me to request an xycomb plot type? If yes, would I do it through this forum? I understand that this wonderful application is free and that it may seem cheeky to ask, but I suspect there may be others who would benefit from such a plot.

Comment: It can be done by modifying the `plotmark` like in this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536568/plotting-3d-bar-plot-in-pgf or by creating a `\newcommand` that takes a point and create two plots like in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/652425/8650.

Comment: @hpekristiansen, thanks for the links. They are not exactly comb plots but I might be able to change them to get what I want, or at least close.

Comment: I was wrong about not being able to trick pgfplots into producing the xycomb plots. After a suggestion from a contributor, I was able to get what I needed. The solution is in the original question noted above. Just FYI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current maintainer does frequent this site, but it is not the right place for feature requests. The issue tracker on GitHub is the right place, I'd think:

https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgfplots/issues

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out.